# incx in BLAS routines

Tags: blas, intelhpc

There are certain BLAS routines that take as parameter the increment of a vector X, namely incX. 
I can't find what the increment is and how it affects the result of the computation.

Can anyone provide some example or any other kind of info ?

Update:

I've found here the best info:
[Intel HPC mkl manual](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/mkl/mklman/GUID-94DE807E-DA2F-4CF6-8A4E-B74628DCC814.htm)

Comment: Did the HPC manual answer your question? Then please remove the update from the question and post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: I think the link is incorrect - I think you're looking for the MK**L** manual, but it links to the intel MP**I** reference; but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 12):

This is quite simple actually.

Let take the example of `axpy(n,a,*x,incx,*y,incy)` which compute : `y = ax + y`

If, for example, you need to compute :

```
y[0] = ax[0] + y[0]; y[1] = ax[2] + y[1]; y[2] = ax[4] + y[2]
```

Then your call is : `axpy(3,a,x,2,y,1)`

But usually, for basic operations, you just have to specify `incx = incy = 1`

Comment: Out of curiosity, are there any operations in matrix algebra that need this type of 'modulo' indexing? Or is it only used for manipulating data? 
I came to this post as I was wondering why the L1 routines need this `inc` parameter, as 1-D vectors should have `inc` = 1.

Comment: I think it's only for manipulating data... If you have a 3D vector of the form (x0, y0, z0, x1, y1, z1, ...) and you have to add a 1D vector to X values for example, this parameter will be useful (`incx = 3`, `incy = 1`).

Comment: Thanks, that's probably quite useful, actually. You could use this when working with complex numbers or [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion). For example `Re(z) + 23`, (where `z` is complex `x + iy`), which discards the imaginary part.

Comment: This general thing is a big deal in numerical linear algebra. BLAS assumes column-major layout for matrices, so if you want to compute the dot product with a matrix row, you'd set incx to the leading dimension (what gemm calls lda/ldb). One of BLAS's legacy issues is that it has little support for strides like this: gemm's lda/ldb function as strides between columns (between rows if transposed) but you can't have simultaneous row and column strides for the same matrix argument, which you need to address arbitrary strided submatrices which show up in tensor contractions, for example.